# Inequality on the cardinal of a distributive lattice according to its height

Tags: combinatorics, lattice-orders

Let $L$ be a finite [distributive lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_lattice). Let $h(L)$ and $|L|$ be (respectively) the height and the cardinal of $L$.

*Question*: Is it true that $|L| \le 2^{h(L)}$ and that the equality holds iff $L$ is boolean?

Comment: By distributive lattice I guess you mean finite distributive lattice? What do you mean by the "height" of a lattice?

Comment: @bof: Yes finite.The height is the maximal length of a chain.

Comment: Thank you. And the "length" of a chain is . . .?

Comment: @bof: the number of edges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every distributive lattice can be embedded in a boolean lattice (this is a well-known fact about distributive lattices). Hence your inequality should hold with equality if $L$ is boolean.

Comment: But how do you prove that $L$ embeds into $B_n$ with $n = h(L)$?

Comment: Yes, see e.g here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/224817/can-a-length-n-distributive-lattice-be-embedded-into-bn

Comment: Oh, I see you were part of the linked thread. Any reason Stanley is wrong?

Comment: Oh yes I remembered, I wrote in comment << I've found  the more complete statement in the book Lattice theory of Garett Birkhoff, corollary 2 p59. >>. This should be explained in details there.